# How do I get my images to display in my Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8

My images are displaying fine in the Visual Studio designer, yet when I debug on my device - nothing displays where the image should be.

I know there's a setting that you need to change in Properties or something but I can't remember nor find anything online that is helping me. *obviously*

I have built the app, made sure that the images Build Action were set to Content, and included the images in the project.

What else am I missing?

In the XML:

```
ImageBrush Opacity=".3" Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Resources/downtown.jpg"
```

Comment: change the images build action to content

Comment: I fixed it. Apparently I have to have my images in the root folder of my app and not in a folder that's in that folder. Ex: Assets.